# pandas exclude dtypes float64, float32 and float16

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

right now I am using `df.select_dtypes(exclude=["float"])` to exclude all "float" columns, but it does not detect e.g a column with dtype float16. I assume that "float" represents the np.float64.

Is there a way to catch all floats like float64, float32 and float16?

Comment: You can do them individually, `df.select_dtypes(exclude=["float32", "float64", "float16", "float8"])`

Comment: Per this code https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.2/pandas/core/frame.py#L4611-L4751 "float" only infers np.float64 and np.float32  See lines 4713 to 4715.

Comment: Thanks you.
Is there something like "float-all"? I want to use a single string to call all of them.

Comment: Nope, not per the code mentioned above where it checks for infer dtypes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.floating`:

```
>>> df.dtypes
a    float16
b    float32
c    float64
d     object
e      int64
dtype: object

>>> df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.floating).dtypes
d    object
e     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Oooo!! Nice, @Corralien.  +1  I just learned something new.  `np.floating`

Comment: @ScottBoston. More information here: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try this MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), columns=['f16', 'f32', 'f64', 'f'])

df['f16'] = df['f16'].astype('float16')
   
df['f32'] = df['f32'].astype('float32')

df['f64'] = df['f64'].astype('float64')

df['f'] = df['f'].astype('float')

df.info()

df.select_dtypes(exclude='float')
```

Output:

```
        f16
0 -0.447021
1  0.468506
2 -0.031860
3  0.540039
4  2.355469
```

Yep, "float" doesn't check for float16.

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude=['float', 'float16'])
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Explicitly defined, "float16".